# Последние входящие сообщения отсутствуют

Tags: дефект, комментарии

В комментариях к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705158/186083) ответу мы с @Эдуард'ом вели диалог. Затем он дал [новый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705174/186083) к данному вопросу и в комментариях уже к этому ответу обратился ко мне.

Но его обращения ко мне не отобразились у меня в Последних входящих сообщениях.

Считаю это багом.

Comment: Эммм. Нет. Оно и не должно было отобразиться. Если вы с кем-то вели беседу на странице - это не значит, что теперь по каждому зову по "@"  на этой странице вас должны уведомлять)) Только после того, как вы хоть раз под этим вопросом/ответом что-то напишите, то только после этого к вам можно обращаться таким образом и ждать уведомлялки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я предполагаю, что это так и есть, но в таком случае такие комментарии, получается, уходят в пустоту.

Comment: Таки, а в чем смысл? Чтобы каждый мог любого дёрнуть без повода? Если хочется обсудить что-то — для этого есть чат)) А для отслеживания темы — есть звезда.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если человек отметился на странице вопроса, то комментарий с обращением к нему на этой странице (хоть к вопросу, хоть к любому ответу) должен доходить.

Comment: @Visman не должен. мне, например, обычно не интересно знать, что там происходит в комментах в соседних ответах

Comment: @Visman мне кажется это редкая нужда, когда человек очень ждет получения сообщений в том же топике из других постов и поэтому в этом просто нет необходимости. Как я писал выше - проще пойти в чат

Comment: Полагаю, что ответ будет "так задумано", но можно сделать небольшое экспресс-голосование.

Answer (score 5):

Это не дефект, а так задумано.

И не надо ничего менять.

Comment: Какие хитрые голосующие. Тут наставили 7 плюсов, а во второй ответ 3 минуса.

Comment: @Visman это не дефект, так как поведение задокументировано: [*"Вы можете отвечать только @имя_пользователя, которые уже прокомментировали данное сообщение."*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Стоит ли это изменить — это отдельный вопрос (с точки зрения пользователя: всё вопросы/ответы на одной странице, поэтому предложение, чтобы `@` работало на той же странице, можно обсудить)

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, о чём там думали разработчики stackoverflow, но я думаю, что нужно иметь возможность обращаться к каждому, кто отметился на странице -- и не разделять, к чему был тот или иной комментарий.